How to run application passed as parameter, after successful install
Here is what I'm trying to achieve: I want to call the installer passing as the first parameter, the EXE file I want to execute after the installation run successfully.
Like this:
c:\downloads\myinstall.exe "c:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\Myapp.exe"

In the above case, I want to call Myapp.exe after the installation finishes.
Is this possible?

First a word of warning: I do not feel well about letting your installer run an arbitrary command. It might get abused. An attacker might make user run your (possibly code-signed) innocent installer with some malicious code. It might even fool an antivirus. At least my solution runs the code without Administrator privileges. But even so...

Your proposed command line syntax conflicts with standard Inno Setup commandline syntax. What if user runs the installer e.g. with /LOG commandline switch like:
c:\downloads\myinstall.exe /LOG=c:\downloads\myinstall.log

You better stick with the switch syntax. E.g. add your own /RUN switch:
c:\downloads\myinstall.exe /RUN="c:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\Myapp.exe"

Also it makes the implementation easier, as you can use {param} "constant". And you can use that in Run section easily:
[Run]
Filename: "{param:RUN}"; flags: skipifdoesntexist

If you need more control, you can of course keep using Pascal code in CurStepChanged. To read the /RUN switch, use:
ExpandConstant('{param:RUN}')


See also Is it possible to accept custom command line parameters with Inno Setup.

I could find how to do it, here is the code if somebody needs it :
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var ResultCode : integer;
begin
if (CurStep = ssDone) then
begin
if paramstr(1) <> '' then
  begin
  Exec(paramstr(1), '', '', SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED, ewNoWait, ResultCode);
  end;
end;
end;


Note that you need at least Inno Setup 6.2 for this to work, as in earlier versions, ParamStr(1) returns /SL5 parameter.

If your are running the installed application, you will probably want to run it without Administrator privileges. So with ExecAsOriginalUser. See also a comment in my answer.
